# Confirm user and password from a list of class objects

Tags: python, list, class

I need to be able to validate the user and the password inputted, but when I run the code below, I'm able to verify only the first element of the list and the second element and so on aren't being verified.

Note: The user and password are stored in the list as class objects [like this:
`admin(user, password)]...`

```
def login(self):
    user_name = input("Please Enter Your Username : ").upper()
    password = input("Please Enter Your Password : ").upper()
    for obj in self.admins:
        while obj.admin_name != user_name and obj.admin_password != password:
            print(" Sorry Username and Password Incorrect Please Re-enter for Validation ")
            user_name = input("Please Enter Your Username : ").upper()
            password = input("Please Enter Your Password : ").upper()
        else:
            print("Greetings,", user_name, "You are Now Logged in the System")
            break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `while` loop only checks for the first user name. You should switch the order of your loops:

```
def login(self):
    user_name = input("Please Enter Your Username : ").upper()
    password = input("Please Enter Your Password : ").upper()
    while True:
        for obj in self.admins:
            if obj.admin_name == user_name and obj.admin_password == password:
                break
        else:
            print(" Sorry Username and Password Incorrect Please Re-enter for Validation ")
            user_name = input("Please Enter Your Username : ").upper()
            password = input("Please Enter Your Password : ").upper()
            continue
        break
    print("Greetings,", user_name, "You are Now Logged in the System")
```

This is also a very bad way to check passwords.

Comment: Thanks man it is working as expected. Can you please tell the other way that you think I should it (the better way)?

Comment: @JoséOrlando It’s complicated to get right. [This blog](https://www.vitoshacademy.com/hashing-passwords-in-python/) talks about some ways to do it better in Python.

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

When you run `break` in your `else` branch you are actually calling it on the `for` loop. Remove the `break` and it should be working as you expect it to

Comment: I also think that using `else` not in the context of an `if` is just confusing and bad coding. Never saw something like that before.

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove `break` from your `else` statement.